# Are Windows OS and software on Windows dependent on specific fonts to run?

Tags: windows-7, fonts

Are software on Windows dependent on specific fonts to run?  What would happen If I delete all fonts from fonts directory and restart the Windows?

Can Windows OS and any software stop working in absence of specific fonts?

My OS is Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because I like to try things, I just made the test. On my dual-boot system, from my Linux, I moved all the content of my `C:\Windows\Fonts` to an other place, thus removing all fonts of my system.

When I then tried to boot my Windows 7 (family edition x64) afterwards, **it instantly dropped me to a recovery environment**, before even showing the traditional Windows loading screen. So it seems some fonts are indeed required.

I was about to say that booting back to Linux and putting back the fonts in place repaired everything, but SuperUser just triggered the "a new answer had been posted" message, and it froze my computer for ~15 seconds and now I have some graphical bug on my pointer.

So I would say that indeed **there are some fonts that should not be deleted on Windows**, probably the one that are protected to avoid they deletion.

Now, I guess I'll try to repair my Windows.

Edit : It seems like a second reboot fixed the remaining instability.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, you have protected system fonts you cannot delete. You can find out if a font is protected, by trying to delete it. If it is protected, you will get an error saying that the font is protected and you can not delete it.